# Upload video on youtube using objective c and google-api-objectivec-client-for-rest

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube-data-api

I want to upload a video to YouTube using Google's latest [library](https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client-for-rest).

Example provided inside it is not working for me on mobile.

Did a lot of searching, but I haven't yet found a complete working example.

Comment: what was the problem in this library

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/hROeU59.png check this photo

Comment: In project setting click the build phase tab , there you find Copy Bundle Resources delete the file which provide you the error, it really solved my problem

Comment: not found in Bundle Resources, code have #import  for that files

Comment: made question easier to understand by cleaning up language

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

hope this link my be helpful for you
https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_uploading_videos

Comment: YouTube Data API (v2) has been officially deprecated as of March 4, 2014